# Can I have a PowerShell SessionConfiguration to be accessed by only one of the ports setup with WinRM?

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting, winrm, jea

I've been working with `JEA` (Jest Enough Administration) in PowerShell recently and would like the JEA sessions to only use a specific non-standard TCP-port.

I'm able to configure the `WinRM` service to listen on multiple ports using

```
winrm s winrm/config/client '@{HTTPS="5986, 7799"}'

winrm enumerate winrm/config/listener
```

But I can't find out how to register a `SessionConfiguration` to bind to only one of the available `WinRM`-ports.

When I list the properties of a `SessionConfiguration`, there is no properties for what port or listener to use.

```
Get-PSSessionConfiguration | select * -First 1
```

I'm only able to specify what port to use when entering the session from the client side using

```
Enter-PsSession <host> -ConfigurationName <MyJEAName> -Port <any available WinRM Port>
```

So, I could in practice connect to any other session I've have permission to as well, even if I only allow the new `WinRM` custom port trough my firewall.

Is there a way to control what PowerShell `SessionConfiguration` to connect to based on TCP-port?

Comment: You need to understand the 7 network layers. SessionConfiguation is an application layer that uses WSMAN (see : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_session_configurations?view=powershell-7.4).  WSMAN is a SOAP connection (see : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WS-Management) which is the  format of the data.  Neither are the Transport Layer which contains the port.  Microsoft has developed tunnels through the windows OS that allow remote command to be executed across a network.  I haven't seen a lot of documentation on these commands.

Comment: Yes, so is it possible to bind the layers together in the way I'd like. WinRM is handling the network part. Is it possible to set up another instance of WinRM for the custom port and bind? The Configured Sessions are plug-ins of WSMAN, right?

Comment: I would use an HTTP controller on a custom port.  HTTP uses TCP as the transport layer.

Comment: You mean like a local redirector? But I can still configure WinRM with a custom port of my own liking. I need a specific Configured Session to be available on a unique port for me to be able to filter it out using a firewall and not just by permission settings.

Comment: Powershell is written in Net library so you ca use any Net method with PS.  So open a HTTP listener on a port.  You can send a SOAP message on HTTP.

Comment: I found following article : https://adamtheautomator.com/winrm-port/

Comment: Thx, but I've already read that. Changing port on WinRM is not the issue. The issue is to single out a specific Configured Session from a firewall perspective. Only one session should be allowed to use the custom port, all others should stick to TCP 5985 :)

Comment: Don't get your 7 network layers mixed up.  The firewall is blocking the port number at the transport layer.  You also need to have authentication at the application layer so only one connection is allowed.  What firewalls often do is to use Port Forwarding and mux all connections onto one port.  Then filter out unwanted data.  Then demux back results back to original port numbers..

Comment: I'm referring to the chained OSI-components. I do know the OSI modell. I'm looking for a dedicated WinRM service for my Configured Session. Much as you can do with i.e. IIS and MSQL.